# Use User Input/Text File as Code

Tags: c++, matlab

Is it possible to treat user input as lines of code in C++?
Or write it to a text file, then run that as c++ code?

I'm writing my own version of matlab, and right now it can do a lot of the numerical stuff, but only if I write the commands in like a script in main. Is there a way I could do it like matlab's command line?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many libraries that allow for scripting like [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) or [Chaiscript](http://chaiscript.com/) which will allow you to take a file of code and execute it. There's also the advantage of being able to make changes to the code and not having to recompile each time.